# Perl: Dereference array of Multidimensional hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hash, dereference

My overall structure has three layers:

The first layer is a hash: **Key**:Continent  **Value**: Country

The second layer is a hash: **Key**: Country  **Value**: 2D array with specific countries

The Third layer is a **2D array**

So far I have my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my %hash=(); #initialize a hash 
my $hash_ref = \%hash;

$hash{continent} = { 
    America => [
    ['North', 'Canada', 'USA'],
    ['South', 'Peru', 'Brazil'],
    ],
    Asia => [
    ['East', 'Japan', 'China'],
    ['Sounth', 'India','Bangladesh'],
    ],
}; 

foreach my $continent (keys %hash) {
    foreach my $country (keys %{ $hash{$continent} }) {
        print "$continent, $country : @{$hash{$continent}{$country}}\n";
    }
}

#print Dumper \%hash;
```

This is the output:

continent, Asia : ARRAY(0x7fb159824890) ARRAY(0x7fb15a004628)

continent, America : ARRAY(0x7fb159803ee8) ARRAY(0x7fb1598240e0)

My question is:
How can I deference the 2D-array in the hash of the hash rather than get their reference??

Comment: Tip: `my %hash=();` can be simplified to `my %hash;`

Comment: Tip: You never use `$hash_ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a choice, you should change your data structure's design to what @bipll [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46248884/589924). Your existing data structure's design requires more complex code than necessary. If you can't, read on.

---

The first loop is incorrect.

This doesn't iterate over the continent names:

```
foreach my $continent (keys %hash) {
```

This does:

```
foreach my $continent (keys %{ $hash{continent} }) {
```

---

The second loop is incorrect.

`$hash{$continent}` now `$hash{continent}{$continent}` is a reference to an array, not a reference to a hash.

---

Fixed:

```
my $by_continent = $hash{continent};
for my $continent_name (keys(%$by_continent)) {
    my $continent = $by_continent->{$continent_name};
    for my $region (@$continent) {
        my $region_name = $region->[0];
        my @country_names = @{$region}[0..$#$region];
        print("$continent_name, $region_name: ", join(', ', @country_names), "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: So in the second and the third line, you iterate all the continent? I am not quite understand your solution although it works pretty good, Could you please explain **$hash{continent}**, **(keys(%$by_continent))**, **@$continent**? Thank you so much.

Comment: It returns the keys in the hash referenced by `$by_continent` (and by `$hash{continent}`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `keys %hash` is a singleton list `('continent')` in your code. May I suppose you really wanted continent names as keys? Then simply write it as

```
my %hash = (America => [...], Asia => [...]);
```

Next, 'North' and 'South' look more like regions inside continents, you've probably missed a layer in design description.

Which suggests something like:

```
my %hash = (America => {North => ['Canada', 'USA'], South => ['Peru', 'Brazil']});
for my $continent (keys %hash) {
    for my $region (keys %{$hash{$continent}}) {
        print "$continent, $region, @{$hash{$continent}{$region}}\n"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
America, North, Canada USA
America, South, Peru Brazil
```

Comment: Thank so much, I just use an example to express my question which has something wrong in the logic...... But I still want to use 2D array in my hash. Maybe just ignore the North and South. Sorry for the confusion.@bipll

Comment: Do you want to splice array of arrays into a single string? Something like `join ' ', map join(' ', @$_), @$array`?